# Transferring an SQL Processor License to a virtual hosted environment

Tags: sql-server, virtualhost, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

My company is currently hosting a service in-house, and we want to move to an externally hosted environment. 
We would then be using a virtual server. I understand that this might be spread across multiple machines, but from my perspective as a customer, this layer is abstracted away - I shouldn't know or care about the hardware that the OS is hosted on.

We have a licensed edition of SQL Server 2008. This is one Processor license.

Will it be a violation of the licensing agreement to use this in a virtual environment?

From the reference guide [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing.aspx) it says

> When licensed Per Processor
>
> With
>   Workgroup, Web, and Standard editions,
>   for each server to which you have
>   assigned the required number of per
>   processor licenses, you may run, at
>   any one time, any number of instances
>   of the server software in physical and
>   virtual operating system environments
>   on the licensed server. However, the
>   total number of physical and virtual
>   processors used by those operating
>   system environments cannot exceed the
>   number of software licenses assigned
>   to that server  For enterprise edition
>   there is an added option: if all
>   physical processors in a machine have
>   been licensed, then you may run
>   unlimited instances of SQL server 2008
>   in one physical and an unlimited
>   number of virtual operating
>   environments on that same machine.

I'm having trouble getting my head around this. Would I theoretically have to get a license for every processor in this virtual environment (which is effectively impossible because I have no way of knowing how many processors there actually are)? Or can I just say that it's hosted on one "virtual" server, so that's OK?

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them?

Comment: Nice question, since MS refers to Physical Processors not virtual or How many Cores a processor has. I would really like to know this. Is it SQL 2008 R2 or pure 2008?

Answer (score 0):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/e/6/1e68f92c-f334-4517-b610-e4dee946ef91/2008%20SQL%20Licensing%20overview%20final.docx uses the phrase ‘A Processor License is required for each processor installed on each operating system environment running SQL Server’, so I'd say it's fine.